# PHP code within HTML style attribute (or Confused by quotes)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, syntax, quotes

I am completely confused about the way I should use PHP code in this line:

```
<div class="post-img" style="backgroung-image:url(' <?php echo $thumbnail[0] ?> ')"></div>
```

It seems to me that it is read as a text in my example.
I also have tried another approach which also didn't work for the same reason, I believe...

```
<?php echo '<div class="post-img" style="backgroung-image:url(' . $thumbnail[0] . ')"></div>' ?>
```

$thumbnail variable contains a link to the main image of a Wordpress post:

```
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ) );
```

Please, give me an advice, how can I apply a dynamic link to a Wordpress post image?

Comment: *It seems to me that it is read as a text in my example.* based on what ? what did you get in HTML ?

Comment: You're missing the `;`

Comment: @WillParky93 if it's the PHP `;` you are talking about, it's optional, good practice yeah but optional, and if it's CSS then if you have one element it's optional too.

Comment: `echo '<div class="post-img" style="backgroung-image:url(\'' . $thumbnail[0] . '\')"></div>';`

Comment: He's opening a php tag, Doesn't it always a need a `;` when followed by opening tag? @teeyo

Comment: @WillParky93 not necessarily, if there are no further lines of code after that.

Comment: I see, I just tested it aswell. Never knew that :) thanks guys

Comment: @WillParky93 like @ADyson said, it's optional, this kind of writing is used in tempalting a lot, I am not a fan of it, I always add a `;` because it's a good practice!

Comment: Guys read the post carefully, that problem is in backgroung-image not backgroung background :) no one is looking at the correct issue

Comment: ADyson and Nobita, thank you so much!!! Both of your advices helped me so much!!!

Comment: ADyson, the approach is that I have to escape HTML qotes (outter ones) and inner qotes are taken as PHP, right?

Comment: @AlexanderPrisazhny you have to escape any quotes included which are intended to be part of the output, and are used as the string delimiter by PHP. So if you open your PHP string using single quotes, then any single quotes needed to be output as part of the string need to be escaped. That's all really. You'd missed out some quotes necessary for the style statement to be correct. As it happens, those quotes also needed to be escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADyson and Nobita gave me the solution in comments to my question, which is:

```
echo '<div class="post-img" style="background-image:url(\'' . $thumbnail[0] . '\')"></div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

If your div has no content then you have to add height in CSS like this:

```
<div class="post-img" style="background:url('<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>')no-repeat; height:200px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="post-img" style="backgroung-
image:url('<?php
wp_get_attachment_image_src(
get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id )[0] ); ?>')">
</div>
```

Some WordPress function directly display the string. No need to echo them.

Answer (score 0):

generall, the results will be like this,

```
array{
    [0] => url,
    [1] => width</em>
    [2] => height</em>
    [4] => is_intermediate
}
```

you can do something like this

```
<?php echo '<div class="post-img" style="backgroung-image:url(' . $thumbnail[0] . ') . $thumbnail[2] ."></div>' ?>
```